# Liferay ExpandoBridge PrincipalException

Tags: liferay-6

I have added a Custom Field named HomeTown under ControlPanel  , set all the permissions to it .

Created a Hook for adding Hometown under th create_account.jsp page .

Now when i am able to set the value of the hometown under the ExtUserLocalService class , i am getting the below exception

```
11:16:22,858 ERROR [http-bio-8080-exec-72][ExpandoBridgeImpl:507] com.liferay.portal.security.auth.PrincipalException
com.liferay.portal.security.auth.PrincipalException
    at com.liferay.portlet.expando.service.permission.ExpandoColumnPermissionImpl.check(ExpandoColumnPermissionImpl.java:36)
```

I have googled for it and found out that this is related to the Permission Issue .

I am new to liferay , could anybody please tell me how to resolve this ??

Thank you very much .

Comment: which version of liferay you are using ?

Comment: Thanks for the response , i am using Liferay 6.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you have to provide UPDATE permission to GUEST role for your custom field "hometown".

Also you don't have to provide code for storing this custom-field.

Liferay's API for add-user takes care of saving custom field for user.

HTH,

Regards,